# Freemarker expected extended hash error

Tags: freemarker

I've added an objectwrapper in freemarker that wraps a type of object as a templateHashModel.   I don't seem to be able to iterate over it - if I try to iterate as a hash, (ie <#list blah as x,y> I get this:

```
Expected an extended hash, but this has evaluated to a hash 
(au.com.amp.common.json.JObjMap wrapped into au.com.amp.blue.templates.FreemarkerAdapterJobj
```

And if I iterate as a list (ie <#list blah as x>) I get

```
Expected a sequence or collection, but this has evaluated to a hash
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution - apparently freemarker wants you now to implement TemplateHashModelEx rather than TemplateHashModel in your object wrapper.  When you do that it works great.

Comment: For listing the contents of a hash it was always required (you said "now"). If you think about it, `TemplateHashModel` doesn't have any methods to do that. Also note that there's `TemplateHashModelEx2` too, which is not required, but makes `<#list blah as x, y>` faster.